# PhpStorm: file watcher on multiple file types + running script from localhost

Tags: phpstorm, less, file-watcher

I want to define some kind of file watcher for multiple file types: `.php`, `.less` and `.js` which will call a script with certain variable parameters (as like from the console) from my current project (localhost).

This should be under "Tools > File Watchers" > custom ?

Unfortunately, it seems, I can only choose from one file type at time - and how would I call the localhost server script under "program"?

Comment: *" it seems, I can only choose from one file type at time"* Easy. Just use "Any Type" there and then define and use Custom Scope (that will include only files with desired name patterns). 1) https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/using-file-watchers.html#ws_filewatcher_type_and_location_of_input_files 2) https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/settings-scopes.html 3) https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-scopes-and-file-colors.html

Comment: *"and how would I call the localhost server script under "program"?"* Calling an URL from a CLI without displaying that page/URL in the browser? -- Use `wget`/`curl` or alike -- they exist for all main OS. Make a shell script (bash/PowerShell/cmd/whatever) and call such a command there (not just one -- can call multiple commands in your script .. since your script will be the "program").

Comment: @LazyOne: there's one problem left: when setting to "any type", phpStorm will cause an endless loop because my external script will generate eg. a .less file - which triggers the file watcher over and over again .. too bad you can't enter like "php;js;less" into "file type" .. so currently i need to create a file watcher for each file type separately.

Comment: Be specific please: show what you have and what the issue is (screenshots / examples). In general I do not see an issue here yet. If your  external script generates a new file (that is of the same type) -- does it generate in the same folder? If not -- you may use exclusion in your Scope pattern. Maybe it makes a file with specific name pattern (e.g. `*.min.css`) -- you can make exclusion for them. Be specific / provide examples.